# Set the value of a C string to a string literal

Tags: c, string

For some reason, I get a compiler error whenever I try to set the value of a C string to a string literal:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char hi[] = "Now I'm initializing a string.";
    hi = "This line doesn't work!"; //this is the line that produced the compiler error
    return 0;
}
```

Also, these are the compiler errors:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:5:8: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[31]’ from type ‘char *’
prog.c:4:10: warning: variable ‘hi’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It appears that the other question is less straightforward than this one (and not as easy to read), so I'm not sure if these questions should be merged.

Answer (score 3):

The way to *copy* a string is the `strcpy()` function:

```
strcpy(hi, "This line should work");
```

Beware: This doesn't check that there's enough room in the target to hold the string. (And no, `strncpy()` is probably [not the solution](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

C does not permit assignment of arrays.

Recommended reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what's happening here is this,

when you write

```
hi = "something here";
```

what happens is, in the memory, the string "something here" is stored, and it returns the pointer to the first element in the memory where the string is stored.

So, it expects the lvalue to be a pointer to char , and not a array of char itself.

So, hi must be declared as `char* hi`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char hi[100];
strlcpy(hi, "something here", sizeof(hi));
```

you should use `strlcpy()` because `strcpy()` and `strncpy()` are not safe.

See : [strncpy or strlcpy in my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987217/strncpy-or-strlcpy-in-my-case)

Comment: Use `sizeof hi`, not `100`. Note that `strlcpy()` is not part of the C standard (nor is it POSIX), so it may or may not be available.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I replaced 100 by sizeof(hi). If `strlcpy` is not available, maybe the OP can use `strcpy`. Both can be an answer to the question. If `strlcpy` is available, best is to use it.