# how to use strncpy correctly?

Tags: c, strcpy, strncpy

I know `strncpy` is a safer version of `strcpy` as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1258550/3512538).

However, when I want to copy from `src` to `dst` and `dst` is not a clean buffer, I get unwanted results, which can be avoided by `strcpy`:

```
char *p = "123";
char a[10] = "aaaaaa";

strncpy(a,p,strlen(p));
printf("%s\n", a);   // 123aaa

strcpy(a,p);
printf("%s\n", a);   // 123 <- desired output, as the trailing a's are garbage
```

In my actual case, I know `strlen(src) < sizeof(dst)` (at least, if that isn't the case, the program will crash a lot sooner), so I can safely `strcpy`.

However, if `strncpy` is what I ***should*** use, then must I add after `dst[strlen(src)] = '\0'` to avoid garbage (or maybe better yet, init the buffer beforehand?)?

Comment: You are defeating the whole advantage of `strncpy` over `strcpy` by this usage. `strncpy(a,p,strlen(p) + 1);` (the `+1` is ommited from your code, but I guess you meant it) is fully equivalent to `strcpy(a,p);`

Comment: `I know strncpy is a safer version of strcpy` It is not. it is *different* (and nearly useless)

Comment: If you copy the exact length of the source string, then [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) will never add the terminator. You might want to use [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) with `strlen(p) + 1` as the length instead. But ***only*** if you know that the length of the source absolutely is smaller than the size of the destination.

Comment: To add to what @joop said, `strlcpy` is considered safer (again, if used properly).

Comment: Your use is only *one of the things* that could go wrong when you use `strncpy()`

Comment: Short answer: don't use `strncpy`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I would not be *that* categorical...

Comment: @EugeneSh. yep, removed "_never_" from comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The third argument of `strncpy` is meant to represent the *size of the target buffer*. And when it fills it up, it doesn't add a null terminating character by design.

If you have sufficient space for the terminator and you insist on `strncpy`, just pass `strlen(p) + 1` so it will not assume it exhausted the target buffer.

Like many already noted by now. This use of `strncpy` defeats the purpose, and is really no better than than a simple call to `strcpy`. The only practical use for `strncpy`, is if you want to overwrite a part of the string in-place (which is the use case you stumbled upon). Though that too is questionable use...

Comment: It would be nice if there was a version of `strncpy` that didn't fill the rest of the target buffer with zeros (if the source string is shorter than the size parameter). That stuff gets expensive.

Comment: @TimRandall - Like `strlcpy`? It was mentioned in the comments too

Answer (score 7):

> how to use strncpy correctly?

When code needs to copy a string to a destination and tolerates the result being not *null character* terminated nor fully copied, use the `sizeof destination` for the size argument:

```
char a[10];
// strncpy(a,p,strlen(p));
strncpy(a, p, sizeof a);

// printf("%s\n", a);
printf("%.*s\n", (int) sizeof a, a);
```

When code wants to copy a string and detect insufficient memory problems via `strncpy()` or needs null character `'\0'` padding, also use the `sizeof destination`.

```
char a[10];
strncpy(a, p, sizeof a);
if (a[sizeof a - 1] != '\0') {
  // insufficient memory
  // Maybe set last last character to the null character 
  a[sizeof a - 1] == '\0';
  // or other more robust handling
  return ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_MEMORY;
}
```

Otherwise do not use `strncpy()`

---

There are more efficient ways to detect insufficient memory than via `strncpy()` when null character `'\0'` padding is not needed.  `strncpy()` zero fills the rest, if any, of the un-copied buffer.  The below consumes much time zero-filling just to provide a insufficiency check.

```
char a[1000];
strncpy(a, "abc", sizeof a);
if (a[sizeof a - 1] != '\0') {
  ....
```

Better alternatives employ `strlen(), strlcpy(), memcpy()`.  [@Deduplicator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52208074/2410359).

See also [strncpy or strlcpy in my case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6987217/2410359).

For a standard C lib one-liner, code could use `snprintf()` and a line of error detection.  A good compiler would be expected to analyse `snprintf(a, sizeof a, "%s", p)` and emit efficient code.

```
// Copy with no overflow.
// 'a' is always null character terminated.
int len = snprintf(a, sizeof a, "%s", p);
if (len < 0 || (unsigned) len >= sizeof a) Report_truncated_copy();
```

Answer (score 2):

`strncpy()` isn't actually a string-function; instead, it deals with which zero-padded sequences of non-zero characters, which together have a known fixed length. It's for example the right tool to fill in data-structures which are thereafter sent to other programs, to the outside, or persisted, to avoid data-leaks.

Trying to use it outside its very specialized niche leads to hideous contortions, and inefficient code.

There are more appropriate ways to go about it, like `strlcpy()` and/or manually using `strlen()` and `memcpy()`.

Comment: Another use is preparing input for fixed-length hashes, in which it is actually important that trailing bytes have a deterministic value so that the hash is the same independent of padding.